# Opening and closing HTML tag in XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, tags

I have this XML:

```
    <XmlTreff IsSub="false" Start="false" Stop="false">
      <Id>Id0</Id>
      <Tittel>Title0</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="false" Start="false" Stop="false">
      <Id>Id1</Id>
      <Tittel>Title1</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="true" Start="true" Stop="false">
      <Id>Id2</Id>
      <Tittel>Title2</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="true" Start="false" Stop="false">
      <Id>Id3</Id>
      <Tittel>Title3</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="true" Start="false" Stop="true">
      <Id>Id4</Id>
      <Tittel>Title4</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="false" Start="false" Stop="false">
      <Id>Id5</Id>
      <Tittel>Title5</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
```

This XML is transformed with XSLT and should produce this HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>
                <a href="doesntmatter">Title0</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="doesntmatter">Title1</a>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="doesntmatter">Title2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="doesntmatter">Title3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="doesntmatter">Title4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div>
                <a href="doesntmatter">Title5</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The thought was that the attributes Start, Stop, and IsSub controls the opening and closing of the tags.

Currently i have this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/XmlSokeResultat/Treff">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="no" xml:lang="no">
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="XmlTreff">
                    <div class="XmlTreffinfo">
                        <xsl:if test="@IsSub = 'false'">                               
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <xsl:element name="a">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Tittel"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </xsl:if>

                        <xsl:if test="@Start = 'true'">
                            <div>
                              <ul>
                        </xsl:if>

                        <xsl:if test="@IsSub = 'true'">
                          <ul>
                          <li>                                    
                            <a>
                              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </a>
                          </li>
                          </ul>
                        </xsl:if>

                        <xsl:if test="@Stop = 'true'">
                              </ul>
                            </div>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </div>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that having opening and closing tags in a syntactical wrong place is not allowed. Do you know how to solve this? (See inside the ifs where the starting div and ul are placed at different place than the closing tags)

EDIT: I can add and remove attributes to the XML, but the element structure must be like this?

EDIT2: I have tried to render out the HTML tags using concat and value-of

```
   <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat('&lt;', '/ul', '&gt;')" />
   <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat('&lt;', '/div', '&gt;')" />
```

Interestingly, IE10 can handle this and but Firefox is not able to render it out correctly.

Comment: I suppose in real live there are more elements with IsSub="flase". Where the elements with sSub="true" should be grouped the the previous    element with  IsSub="flase". I not the solution is quit easy.

Comment: Yes there are more elements and attributes. The example is a stripped down version of the core problem I'm having

Comment: I have tried to place the opening and closing tags inside CDATA, but the HTML will not be parsed by the HTML parser for some reason

Comment: If there are some adjustments to xml attributes that can be done? I can add and remove attributes to the XML but the element structure must be left alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a key based solution to group you XmlTreff elements.

```
<xsl:key name="kChildren" match="XmlTreff[@IsSub='true']"
              use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::XmlTreff[@IsSub='false'][1])"/>
```

And than use templates as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="kChildren" match="XmlTreff[@IsSub='true']"
              use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::XmlTreff[@IsSub='false'][1])"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="XmlTreff[@IsSub = 'false']" >
        <div>
            <a href="doesntmatter">
                <xsl:value-of select="Tittel"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kChildren', generate-id())" />
        </ul>

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="XmlTreff[@IsSub = 'true']"  >
        <li>
            <a href="doesntmatter">
                <xsl:value-of select="Tittel"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*" >

        <html>
            <body>
                <div class="XmlTreffinfo">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="XmlTreff[@IsSub = 'false']" />
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Attention: I ignore the Start and Stop attribute. Only meaning for this could be to have a hint for first an last entry.

With this input:
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

```
<xml>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="false" Start="false" Stop="false">
        <Id>Id1</Id>
        <Tittel>Title1</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="true" Start="true" Stop="false">
        <Id>Id2</Id>
        <Tittel>Title2</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="true" Start="false" Stop="false">
        <Id>Id3</Id>
        <Tittel>Title3</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="true" Start="false" Stop="true">
        <Id>Id4</Id>
        <Tittel>Title4</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>

    <XmlTreff IsSub="false" Start="false" Stop="false">
        <Id>Id1</Id>
        <Tittel>Title12</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="true" Start="true" Stop="false">
        <Id>Id2</Id>
        <Tittel>Title22</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="true" Start="false" Stop="false">
        <Id>Id3</Id>
        <Tittel>Title32</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="true" Start="false" Stop="true">
        <Id>Id4</Id>
        <Tittel>Title42</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
</xml>
```

It will generate following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="XmlTreffinfo">
      <div>
        <a href="doesntmatter">Title1</a>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="doesntmatter">Title2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="doesntmatter">Title3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="doesntmatter">Title4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div>
        <a href="doesntmatter">Title12</a>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="doesntmatter">Title22</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="doesntmatter">Title32</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="doesntmatter">Title42</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added some more XML in the sample above for clarity. Do you believe that it will still render out the xml correctly? (There are some XmlTreff that does not have any sub elements)

Comment: Yes it should also work with changed input. ;-) This was the reason to use the key.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a great example to use XSLT in a proper and simple way. It can be solved using three templates. You don't need start and stop attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <div>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//XmlTreff[@IsSub='false']"/>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//XmlTreff[@IsSub='true']"/>
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="XmlTreff[@IsSub='false']">
    <div>
        <a href="doesntmatter">
            <xsl:value-of select="Tittel"/>
        </a>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="XmlTreff[@IsSub='true']">
    <li>
        <a href="doesntmatter">
            <xsl:value-of select="Tittel"/>
        </a>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sorry @hr_117: I only saw that amount of code and did not realize that your solution is about the same as mine except I did not use keys for simplicity

Comment: The order is important in the xml. What i am trying to do is to render out a parent search hits with sub hits underneath. The parent will always go infront of the IsSub=true elements. I will add some more to the sample xml for clarity.

Comment: @Andreas: Nice sort version. But this only will work if there is only one entry with XmlTreff[@IsSub='false']. If there are more the key solution starts to be shorter.

Comment: @StianStandahl Did you try the key base vestion. Should still comply the changed requirements.

Comment: I will try this @hr_117, I will keep you posted.

Comment: @hr_117: I admit grouping is necessary as soon as the data gets complicated. The main task of my answer was not to create a complete real life solution but to give an idea how XSLT works that solves the example and is easy enough to motivate understanding it. I think "xsl:if" should be avoided and are one reason people don't understand XSLT.

Comment: @StianStandahl: If you control the data structure (seems like because you added start/stop attributes) it might be easier to let the sub-elements be real childs of their parents, so you could apply them from the parents template. If that is not possible, you could attach the parents id with the sub to apply templates like XmlTreff[parent::XmlTreff/id=$myParentId]

Comment: The reason for that the element structure cannot be changed is due to customers already using that structure in retrieving the search results. If i change the element structure, they must also change how they parse the result.

Comment: I have tried the other suggestion by adding the parent id. But if there was a couple of hundred search hits, the xslt tranformation was quite slow.

Comment: @StianStandahl Therefore you should use a key based solution.

Comment: @StianStandahl: Having a couple of hundred elements to be searched is a reason of its own to use keys as suggested by hr_117, so go on his solution. If my post was helpful to show you the idea of using XSLT, I'm satisfied as I believe in its simplicity and beauty which is often overlooked because of misusing.

Answer (score -1):

What if the starts and stops doesnt match up? I think this is a hopeless task, to be honest. Either make your XML have the structure directly, as in:

```
<XmlTreff>
    <Id>Id1</Id>
    <Tittel>Title1</Tittel>
    <XmlTreff>
        <Id>Id2</Id>
        <Tittel>Title2</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff>
        <Id>Id3</Id>
        <Tittel>Title3</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff>
        <Id>Id4</Id>
        <Tittel>Title4</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
</XmlTreff>
```

or, if you cannot do that, define the structure in a separate section, where you refer to your items with, for instance, the Id tag value.

```
<structure>
    <item idref="Id1">
        <item idref="Id2" />
        <item idref="Id3" />
        <item idref="Id4" />
    </item>
</structure>
```

Comment: If you know where to put the sub, start and stop stuff, I fail to understand why you cannot make the second alternative; it can even be in a separate file. Life would be soo much easier :-)

Answer (score -1):

I made up a slightly more complex version of your example to make sure I exercise your model completely:

```
<document>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="false" Start="false" Stop="false">
        <Id>Id0</Id>
        <Tittel>Title0</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="false" Start="false" Stop="false">
        <Id>Id1</Id>
        <Tittel>Title1</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="true" Start="true" Stop="false">
        <Id>Id2</Id>
        <Tittel>Title2</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="true" Start="false" Stop="false">
        <Id>Id3</Id>
        <Tittel>Title3</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="true" Start="false" Stop="true">
        <Id>Id4</Id>
        <Tittel>Title4</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="false" Start="false" Stop="false">
        <Id>Id5</Id>
        <Tittel>Title5</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="true" Start="true" Stop="false">
        <Id>Id6</Id>
        <Tittel>Title6</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
    <XmlTreff IsSub="true" Start="false" Stop="false">
        <Id>Id7</Id>
        <Tittel>Title7</Tittel>
    </XmlTreff>
</document>
```

Then using modes and copy for following subsequences the following XSLT will parse out your elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <div>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>                    
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="XmlTreff[@IsSub='false']">
        <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="link"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="XmlTreff" mode="link">
        <a href="doesntmatter"><xsl:value-of select="Tittel"/></a>       
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="XmlTreff[@IsSub='false' or preceding-sibling::XmlTreff[@IsSub='false']]" mode="toFirstFalse"/>

    <xsl:template match="XmlTreff[not(@IsSub='false') and not(preceding-sibling::XmlTreff[@IsSub='false'])]" mode="toFirstFalse">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="XmlTreff[@IsSub='true' and not(preceding-sibling::XmlTreff[1][@IsSub='true'])]">
        <xsl:variable name="following">
            <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::XmlTreff"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="subset">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$following" mode="toFirstFalse"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="(.|$subset)" mode="children"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="XmlTreff" mode="children">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="link"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="XmlTreff[@IsSub='true' and preceding-sibling::XmlTreff[1][@IsSub='true']]"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Into the following result:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div>

         <div><a href="doesntmatter">Title0</a></div>

         <div><a href="doesntmatter">Title1</a></div>

         <ul>
            <li><a href="doesntmatter">Title2</a></li>
            <li><a href="doesntmatter">Title3</a></li>
            <li><a href="doesntmatter">Title4</a></li>
         </ul>



         <div><a href="doesntmatter">Title5</a></div>

         <ul>
            <li><a href="doesntmatter">Title6</a></li>
            <li><a href="doesntmatter">Title7</a></li>
         </ul>


      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.